# Turn off Content Preview Enabled when creating a subsystem in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a script that generates a subsystem and I want to turn off the Content Preview.  My script has the following line:

`add_block('built-in/Subsystem',[sys '/subsystemA'],'Position',[1150 100 1400 980],'AttributesFormatString','Version: %<Tag>','Tag','5.0.0','ContentPreviewEnabled','off');`

This is not working in R2019B.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `ContentPreviewEnabled` flag after the block has been created.

```
blk = add_block('built-in/Subsystem',[sys '/subsystemA'],'Position',[1150 100 1400 980],'AttributesFormatString','Version: %<Tag>','Tag','5.0.0');
set_param(blk,'ContentPreviewEnabled','off');
```

I've tried your initial command in R2018b and R2020a (what I have installed) but was unable to recreate any issue with the content preview not being turned off.